# Laravel 4 - Downloading a CSV and returning a true response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have some code which takes an array and puts it into csv format, at the moment, it saves the file to the server, but i want the user to be able to download the csv instead and nothing im trying is working.

Currently my function looks like this

```
public function postForm() {

    $exportType = Input::get('exportType');
    $data = Session::get('data');

    if ( $exportType == 'csv' ) {

        $fp = fopen('csvExport.csv', 'w');

        foreach( $data as $fields ) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }

        fclose($fp);

    } else {

        // Other function here

    }

    return Response::json( array('result' => true) );

}
```

Can anyone help me out please, any help would be really greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to download the file - you need to 'return' the file to them as the Response

```
 return Response::download('csvExport.csv');
```

Comment: Hey, i have tried that ... But it just returns the data not any downloading

Comment: Are you trying to do it via ajax (I just noticed you were returning JSON before)? You cant download via ajax.

Comment: No, i replaced the return line with what you wrote

Comment: But how are you calling the page? What is displayed when you go to the page?

Comment: I am calling the postForm function from an ajax post call

Comment: ...so when I said "Are you trying to do it via ajax" and you replied "no" - you should have replied "yes". You cannot download via ajax

Comment: This answer might help you change the approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request