# Download an excel file in JQuery-AJAX request from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, download, closedxml

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I generated a excel file using [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

It works well in non-ajax call. Here is my controller action method

```
 // Prepare the response
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + reportHeader + ".xlsx\"");

 // Flush the workbook to the Response.OutputStream
 using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
     MyWorkBook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
     memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
     memoryStream.Close();
 }
 Response.End();
```

Now I am trying to do it via an ajax request. But the file is not sent from mvc controller.

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,  
                contentType: false,  
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                success: function (response) {

                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });
```

How can i accomplish it? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just don't need an AJAX call to do this.

Comment: @king.code I want to do it in ajax response.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request) then. It's PHP but that's the way I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not?
ramiramilu was right about using `window.location` and `iframe`. 
I did the same thing but for ASP.NET MVC3.

I would suggest to use controller which returns `FileContentResult`

FYI about `FileContentResult` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

And finally how I did it (Controller):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpStatusCodeResult CreateExcel()
    {
        XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(XLEventTracking.Disabled); //create Excel

        //Generate information for excel file
        // ...

        if (wb != null)
        {
            Session["ExcelResult"] = wb;
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public FileContentResult ExcelResult(string reportHeader) //it's your data passed to controller
    {

        byte[] fileBytes = GetExcel((XLWorkbook)Session["ExcelResult"]);
        return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, reportHeader + ".xlsx");
    }
```

In model (you can remove static if you wish, and call it with instance)

```
public static byte[] GetExcel(XLWorkbook wb)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveAs(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("CreateExcel")",
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            cache: false,
            statusCode: {
                400: function () {
                    alert("Sorry! We cannot process you request");
                },
                200: function () {
                    $("#fileHolder")
                    .attr('src', 
                    '@Url.Action("ExcelResult")?reportHeader=' + 
                    reportHeader);
                }
            }
        });
```

BTW, I removed all exception handlers to simplify the code, but I assume You can do it yourself.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is "fileHolder" used for?

Comment: Id for iframe. Purpose using same window.

Comment: statusCode part solved my problem because it was not hitting the success. thanks.

Comment: do i need to add any reference to get XlWorkbook in MVC5?

Comment: Sure. You can go to link in the question about closedXML

Answer (score 3):

You cannot **DIRECTLY** download a file using AJAX, but you can download a file using `window.location` in conjunction with AJAX to make the file downloaded. What I mean is that if you use AJAX GET/POST all the file content will be in memory of the browser but cannot be saved to disk (because of JavaScript limitations).

Instead you can use `window.location` to point to a URL which in turn will fetch the file and prompt the save/open prompt. Or else you can use a hidden `iFrame` and set the `src` attribute of iFrame with the URL from which will download the file.

Comment: Read comment on OP from @king.code.  AJAX requests are possible and he references an example.  This solved the problem for me and yes, it is possible to download a file with AJAX if you find the need to do so.

Comment: @jaredbaszler, if you look at the king.code post, even they used window.location. Can you clearly explain the reason behind down vote?

Comment: Because you clearly state "you cannot download a file using AJAX" as your first sentence above.  Which as you later state in your own post is not true.  At first glance I was going to look for another alternative because of the way you presented your argument.  Thankfully I read the response from @king.code above and found what I was looking for.  Technically you are right about not downloading via AJAX but I wanted to utilize other features of AJAX with using window.location.  The way you present your argument made me think that wasn't possible.

Comment: Agreed with your point, in that case a EDIT would make the essence of answer more appropriate, than projecting the entire answer as wrong one.