# Send text as a download file

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to send simple text string as a file, that being downloaded under certain name upon request. Can't seems to figure out why this code fails.

```
var text_ready = "This is a content of a txt file."
res.setHeader('Content-type', "application/octet-stream");
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.txt');
res.send( new Buffer(text_ready) );
```

When this code executes, I receive only a XHR response (with that string as a content), but no download is being initiated. But I expected that receiveing this response will force browser to download a file with `file.txt` as a name having content of the string above.

How to fix that? What am I doing wrong?

Maybe it will be important: working under Chrome 41 on Windows.

**EDIT:** it seems that I have to describe a bit deeper. The workflow is the following:

- page contains a table cells with angular `ng-click` events attached to each of them
- when clicking a GET request is being sent to "/download" using jQuery's $.get("/download")
- server have route to handle this GET requests
- what I need to achieve is that a certain text string is being send to user and saved as a file (so that a download is being initiated upon click, shortly speaking)

#### testings

1. It **works** when I **navigate** manually to that url by entering this url to address bar and pressing enter
2. It **does not work** when I **click with mouse** on that cell - the request is sent, the response is received but no download is initiated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tested on my node.js version 0.12.2, Windows 7, Chrome and Firefox

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var text_ready = "This is a content of a txt file."


res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/force-download','Content-disposition':'attachment; filename=file.txt'});

res.end( text_ready );
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

I think that you're not running the latest version of node.js. Maybe you can change only Content-type header, which might work. Also, you can use `res.end( new Buffer(text_ready) );`. I've tested it.

**EDITED:**
*How to download file from node.js with javascript(jQuery onclick) call:*

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on('click',function(){
        window.location = 'http://127.0.0.1:1337/';
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

`<button id="button">Download</button>`

I'm sure you know how to rewrite from jQuery to angularJS. :)
I think that this is better than using an Ajax call. If you really need Ajax, I'll find out how to do it.

Comment: I have node 0.11.30 and express 4.3.2. Still doesn't work. Can this be due to that this is a POST request using  jQuery (not the GET one)?

Comment: You can't download file with ajax call. Is it possible to use iframe? Somethink like `<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:1337/" />` Or try with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request

Comment: I have edited initial question to describe better what I am trying to do. As I undestand the problem is due to ajax..

Comment: got it working using `window.location = "/download/"`, but I will mark your answer as acceptable anyway.