# Detect When PHP File Returns PDF File

Tags: php, pdf, download, detect

I am trying to detect when the PDF file is returned from the .php file that is generating it. Obviously when the download link appears then it is returned. However, I would like to implement a loading screen while the pdf file is being create.

Below I have the function that runs the .php file that generates the pdf.

Thank you!

```
function popupClick2 (){
    var popupObj2 = {};
    var c = '0';
    var p = '0';
    var i = '0';

    document.location.href = 'popupAjax2.php?yearPop='+$('#year').val()
                                                      +'&rangeD='+$('#rangeD').val()
                                                      +'&checkboxI='+i
                                                      +'&checkboxP='+p
                                                      +'&checkboxC='+c
                                                      +'&type='+$('#pdfcsv').val();
    closePopup2();
}
```

Comment: I posted bellow what you should do, not the pure written code, as there are a lot of answered questions of how you can accomplish what you need. Please ask there for further information, or update this question with your updated code, if it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you are on page **preview_book.php**.  Here you have a link **Download PDF**. On this **preview_book.php** you should implement an javascript code that makes an ajax request to your **download_pdf.php** file.

Here is a link how you could do it: [download file using an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request)

On that ajax request, you also attach beforeSend: function(){} and onComplete:function(){}.

On beforeSend function you should make an loading gif visible, and onComplete you should hide it.

Full documentation on Jquery AJAX request [is here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).