# File downloading using AJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating simple file downloading script using AJAX in PHP. My script is not working. Means it displaying the content of the pdf/doc file below download link after clicking on it. Below image will illustrate the problem.

[image]

Below is my code

**AJAX and HTML**:

```
$(function() {
$(".download_link").click(function() {       
    var test = $("#content").val();
    var dataString = 'content='+ test;          
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "download_file.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){            
        $("#display").after(html);
        document.getElementById('content').value='';            
    }
});
return true;
});
});

<a href="#" class="download_link" id="d_link">
```

**PHP Script: (download_file.php)**

```
<?php     
ob_start();
$file = 'file.doc';
header("location:".$file);    
?>
```

Comment: You can't simply embed a file within a web page by just echoing it's contents.  Your upload script should save the file and return a download link to it instead.

Comment: You cant download a file using using ajax as you cant write the ajax result to a file using js at least. Its restricted !!!!

Comment: is any another way to download file using ajax or jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [download file using an ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using  `$("#display").after(html);` thats why its displaying  the content of the file. You can download the file by following code.

```
$(function() {
$(".download_link").click(function() {       
    var test = $("#content").val();
    var dataString = 'content='+ test;          
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "download_file.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){            
            window.location = 'your_file.pdf';
    }
});
return true;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is incorrect.

With your script you are trying to append *file.doc* contents into DOM object -> browser do not know on AJAX request how to manage document's encoding, it will not work.

For downloading documents I would not use AJAX, I think would be fine if you just open a new window with the document's url and let the borwser to manage the content's response:

```
window.open("download_file.php");
```

If you just want to display documents contents in the same page, I would use an iframe as follows:

```
<form action="download_file.php" method="GET" target="docIframe">
    <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
</form>

<iframe name="docIframe" width="600px" height="500px"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
You need to set header content type to tell the browser how it renders the content for PDF or DOC.
<?php
   //Set header for pdf
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='file_to_download.pdf'");
    readfile("original.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: I have never seen something like this, even if you set the _Content-type:application/pdf_ you cannot just attach it to a DOM object.