# JavaScript Prompt download in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, superagent

Im simply trying to download a file from the server and prompt the download in the browser for the user to see.

What i have right now:
Client

```
export function downloadTemplateAction(questionnaire) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(downloadTemplateRequestAction(questionnaire));

    return request
      .get(downloadGETUrl)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Download ERROR", err)
          dispatch(downloadTemplateFailureAction(err, questionnaire));
        } else {
          console.log("Download Success", res.body)
          dispatch(downloadTemplateSuccessAction(res.body, questionnaire));
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Server:

```
export function downloadTemplateDocument(req, res){
    res.download('template/Example.docx');
    res.end();
}
```

Im facing two problems:

**First**: When trying to download the file via the function of the Client, the response body is null but success and nothing more happens.

**Second**: When contacting the get API via the browser  localhost:3002/api/download, the download works but the received file is empty. There should be text in it.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Should your downloadTemplateDocument function not return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Browser can't prompt a download progress because your request is sent via XMLHttpRequest.
Physical access to the file is needed for the browser to be aware of any download.

You could use [download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) to tell browser to download linked ressource.

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20830337/4128783)