# How to send parameter from javascript to controller in laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

My code is like this :

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showAjaxPdf('{{ $row->file_path }}');"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a>
```

My javascript code is like this :

```
  function showAjaxPdf(file_path){
//example : file_path = assets/images/myfile.pdf
                $.post("news/test", { name: file_path } ); 
            }
```

My function test in controller :

```
public function postTest($file_path)
    {  
        return response()->download($file_path);       
    }
```

When I click on the pdf icon, failed to send parameter from javascript to controller

I wish, when click on the pdf icon, appear like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1VFw.jpg

Thank you

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830337/453348

Answer (score 0):

You are posting parameter `name` not `$file_path`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function postTest(Request $request)
{  
    $file_path = $request->input('name');
    return response()->download($file_path);       
}
```

make sure your `$file_path` meaningful for your server
to resolve path on server public folder `public_path()` will get you `<driver>/<dir>/<app dir>/public/images/smail.png`  then you can download it

`return response()->download(public_path() + $file_path);`

Comment: parameter successfully sended to the controller. But, but pdf(http://imgur.com/uhPfOWL)  do not appear

Answer (score 0):

This is how you retrieve input in Laravel 5.

```
public function postTest()
{  
    $file_path = Request::input('name');     // get the value that was posted
    return response()->download($file_path); // return something    
}
```

Also, I am assuming that in your routes.php file, you have "news/test" routing to `postTest`

https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#retrieving-input

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

have you tried exclamation mark (!!) ?

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showAjaxPdf('{!! $row->file_path !!}')">
```