# Open Save As Dialogue for Downloading with Javascript and Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, firefox, greasemonkey

I am writing a script which shall download a pdf instead of showing it.
I am using Firefox as a webbrowser (latest version) and I installed greasemonkey (latest version) and I am using the Ubuntu OS (14.04).

This is the function I wrote:

```
function downloadFile(finalURL){
    // Create new (invisible) link:
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = finalURL;
    link.download = 'test.pdf';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

However, the browser still shows the file instead of popping up the "Save as"-Dialogue.

I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have to disable `PDFjs`

Comment: If I disable PDFjs it always downloads it. However I want the script to create download-links and if I click on them without my script enabled they shall be displayed in the browser, so this is unfortunately not the solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request