# How to export a HTML table to Excel supported by Chrome and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, export-to-excel

On my MVC project I have a HTML table bound with Knockout.

I'm trying to Export the table to Excel.

I tried on client side with JavaScript:

```
self.exportToExcel = function () {
    javascript: window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $("#tableToprint").innerHTML());
}
```

OR:

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table cellspacing="0" rules="rows" border="1" style="color:Black;background-color:White;border-color:#CCCCCC;border-width:1px;border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:9pt;text-align:center;">{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function (table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', endings: 'native' });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'export.xlsx')
    } else {
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
}
})()
```

But both codes work in Chrome but not in IE.

I would like to do it on client side using JavaScript or jQuery but if there is not a solution that is supported by both browsers I can also do it in server side with an AJAX Post Request to my Web API.

**How can I export a HTML table to Excel supported by Chrome and IE using JavaScript/jQuery OR AJAX and Web API?**

Any advice?

Comment: If you're using MVC, you'd be better off creating the excel xml server-side with a simple `FileStreamResult` action.  Then it's browser-independent and not limited to browser address bar limitations.  You can use OpenXml SDK (or any wrapper).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I can't do it through MVC server side, because throughout all the project for any server side actions I made AJAX call to my Web API, I don't have code on my MVC Controllers...

Comment: Why does that stop you adding a new 'ExcelDownloadController' ?

Comment: I would rather create this Controller on my Web API, but I'm not sure how to do it, would you be able to guide me?

Comment: You can not get the browser to handle a file-save via AJAX (maybe can with HTML5 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request).  The reason to use `FileStreamResult` is that it instructs the browser what to do with the file (ie show inline or provide a download prompt depending on browser and end-user options).  ie does everything you need.   So your WebAPI might generate the excel-xml itself, but can't tell the browser how to handle it.  You need `content-disposition` and all that other stuff (which the ActionResult above does for you).

Comment: It can be done all on the client in the latest browsers but <=IE8 will not work, no matter what you do.  If this needs to be backwards compatible then use server side function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the [eligrey.filesaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js) 
then just use it as

window.saveAs(blob,filename);

based on jparaya's answer I created a little sample in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xho71KpwCNso8pOChZxT?p=preview), to save the file with filesaver
It does the same as jparaya's code except for the saving part:

```
function fnExcelReport(id, name) {
  var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
  tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
  tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';
  tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
  tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';
  tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
  var exportTable = $('#' + id).clone();
  exportTable.find('input').each(function (index, elem) { $(elem).remove(); });
  tab_text = tab_text + exportTable.html();
  tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';
  var fileName = name + '_' + parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000000) + '.xls';

  //Save the file
  var blob = new Blob([tab_text], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8" })
  window.saveAs(blob, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried it but couldn't get it to work what are the parameters that I should pass in? the table ID? what is this 'blob' parameter? Thank you!!

Comment: I edited my original answer. Hope this makes it more clear

Comment: Working!! both in IE and Chrome! But I have 2 questions: 1) is there a way to save it as .xlsx file? If I change it manually the file become corrupted. 2) Is there a way to get rid of the excel warning message(trusted source etc..)? Thank you SO much!

Comment: Hm.. Nope.I've tried some things, but couldn't get that to work.Please share it if you find out how to do it

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this warning "The file format and extension of 'file.xls' dont match." using this method?

Comment: Seems like a more clean solution than the one used in tableToExcel

Answer (score 6):

Hmm I'm not really sure what's your problem. Looking at the code, seems everything is fine. Anyway, here I send you a simple implementation that I use, which can help you. Uses the same logic. Perhaps I check first IE version and that's why this works.

This sample has a simple link that executes the *fnExcelReport* function, passing table name and the excel name. I clone first, because my knockout code switches between view/edit modes with inputs. You can remove the clone and $(elem).remove() if you don't have that problem.

**Edit: this version now implements the download for Chrome without the `<a>` tag in the html**

```
function fnExcelReport(id, name) {
    var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';
    tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
    var exportTable = $('#' + id).clone();
    exportTable.find('input').each(function (index, elem) { $(elem).remove(); });
    tab_text = tab_text + exportTable.html();
    tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    var fileName = name + '_' + parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000000) + '.xls';
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
                type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
            });
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        }
    } else {
        var blob2 =  new Blob([tab_text], {
            type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
        });
        var filename = fileName;
            var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
            elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob2);
            elem.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(elem);
            elem.click();
            document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it now, it's working perfectly in IE but not in Chrome, any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: I updated the code. Now you don't need to add the link on the HTML to download on Chrome.