# How to convert a static html table to excel form using .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, excel

I have a project a part of which is to convert an html table into an excel file. The fields in the table will be static.

There are a bunch of solutions on the site but they don't really seem to work for me.

I'm using visual studio 2015 edition

Comment: What solutions have you tried yet? Have you looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040942/how-to-export-a-html-table-to-excel-supported-by-chrome-and-ie) for example.

Comment: *There are a bunch of solutions on the site but they don't really seem to work for me.* ... it is better if you include the *bunch* you looked at and explain why they didn't solve your particular problem. Now we'll have to redo your research and probably come up with the same solutions you already tried which is a waste of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Question header says static html table..... ok i will give approach to this problem something like this....

use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) to grab data from static table, grabbed data insert into a proper object list according to table data type....

from that point generate a excel is not a big issue....