# How to specify the filename in ajax while exporting in excel format

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In this code I want to specify the filename when downloading the excel format.

```
if(comp_id != "Select Company")
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/export.php',
    data: {
      action: 'compreport', 
      'comp':comp_id,   
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function (output) {
      $("#ereportview").html(output);
      window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=ereportview]').html()));
      e.preventDefault();
    },
    async: false
  });  
}
```

Comment: please can you explain more?? What filename

Comment: i want to assign downloaded excel filename in that code

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25866873 if you can download without ajax as well.

Comment: Its take random file name.

Comment: I know there is HTTP header Content-Disposition to specify download file name. But this is HTTP Response header. I don't know how to set header in data url schema. One possible solution, you could add meta data in your 'div[id$=ereportview]'. Just add <meta name="content-disposition" content="attachment; filename=excel.csv">. I have try this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this [download function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/4182676) in your `success` callback

```
function download(filename, text, mime) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:'+mime+',' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
if(comp_id != "Select Company") {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/export.php',
    data: {
      action: 'compreport', 
      'comp':comp_id,   
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function (output) {
      download("yourfile.xlsx", output, 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
    },
    async: false
  });  
}
```

you can specify MIME for the type of content you're downloading. You can get that from [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)

Comment: i want to download in pdf format means how to edit this code

Comment: i need the output in pdf format your code is for excel file

Comment: @KalaivaniM The question is "How to specify the filename in ajax while exporting in **excel format**".  If you have a new question, please ask as a new question.