# Generating PDF via Ajax call in MVC

Tags: ajax

I wanted to Generate a PDF report using Ajax call, I can able to generate it successfully with below statement but how can ii achieve this using AJAX call

```
 $('#printReports').click(function () {
     window.location.href = "/StoreProfile/PrintReports?selectedReport=" + $("#bindReports").val() + "&storeNumber=" + '@Model.StoreProfileAssociation.StoreNumber';
}
```

Instead of above statement i want it to generate PDF using AJAX, the below code i have tried but seems does not working, kindly help me with some good suggestions

```
$('#printReports').click(function () {                 
            $.ajax(
                   {
                       type: 'GET',
                       data: { 'selectedReport': selectedReport },
                       datatype: "json",
                       url: "/StoreProfile/PrintReports",
                       success: function (data) {
                           var json = data;
                           console.log(json);
                           //$('#printReports').html('');
                           //$('#_genericReport').html(data);
                           window.location.href = "/StoreProfile/PrintReports";
                       },
                       error: function (result) {
                           showAlert("Error", 'Failed to load the result');
                       }
                   })
  I tried in the above method but didn't worked.
```

Comment: I think file downloads are not possible with AJAX calls. You can just use `window.location="/download/StoreProfile/PrintReports?filename=report.xls";`

Comment: Actually i have to generate the PDF report on the same page. then i'll be sending it to printer. Is any other way to achieve using ONLY AJAX CALLS

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830337/1793718. You can just use `window.location="/download/StoreProfile/PrintReports?filename=report.xls";`

Comment: I have tried this way but it didn't generating the PDF file success:  $.ajax(
                   {
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: { 'selectedReport': selectedReport, 'storeNumber' :storeNumber},
                       datatype: "json",
                       url: "/StoreProfile/PrintReports",function (data) {
                           var json = data;
                           console.log(json);                           
                           window.location = "/StoreProfile/Index";}