# How I can download uploaded file?

Tags: php, file

Im trying to download uploaded file in my database but I cant. Please see the below code.

> $filepath = "upload/".$filename;

```
   <table class="main_table" border="1">
       <tr class="tb_row">
           <?php
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
           ?>
         <td class="tb_dt"><?php echo $row['position']?></td>
         <td class="tb_dt"><?php echo $row['trainings']?></td>
         <td class="tb_dt"><?php echo $row['tr_date']?></td>
        <td><a href="download.php?name=<?php echo $row['img_path'];?>"> download </a></td>
     </tr>
 <?php        }     ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: use html5 download attribute

Comment: May be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request

Comment: use download attribute like this. <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>

Comment: Im looking to download with php, not with AJAX.

Comment: and also close </tr> outside the loop.

Comment: Do you want to download file on server or Client side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
download.php
<?php

  $file= $_GET['name'];// make sure it should be a correct path
  if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Comment: still nothing, maybe here is the problem "<td><a href="download.php?name=<?php echo $row['img_path'];?>"> download </a></td> "

Comment: $row['img_path'] is this contains full image path with image name?

Comment: $filetemp = $_FILES['file_img']['tmp_name'];
                                    $filename = $_FILES['file_img']['name'];
                                    $filetype = $_FILES['file_img']['type'];
                                    $filepath = "upload/".$filename;
                                    move_uploaded_file($filetemp,$filepath );

Comment: $row['img_path'] is displaying full file path