# Download PDF by using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, file, download

I'm trying to automatically download PDF, not open in a new window or the same window. I am running an AJAX and in ajax response I'm passing a PDF URL which must be downloaded. I want to download the file by using jQuery.

I want the functionality like `<a href="url" download></a>`

This link works but must work by jQuery and not appending anchor tag. If possible rather create an anchor and trigger that. How can I do that?
Any suggestion can be useful.

Comment: Please see this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax) or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)