# How can I download zip file from controller on client side? Spring boot

Tags: java, arrays, file, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have `file.zip` in DB like `BLOB`. I want create method in Spring controller for download this file on client side.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadResolution/{resolutionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadResolution(@PathVariable("resolutionId") Long resolutionId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Resolution resolution = resolutionService.findOne(resolutionId);
        ResolutionArchive resolutionArchive = resolution.getResolutionArchive();
        if (resolutionArchive == null) return;
        byte[] archive = resolutionArchive.getArchive();
        //this byte[] archive - my zip file from db
    }
```

How can I change this methot In order to download this on client side?

User press download button. Methos get data from DB in byte[] and user can download it.

EDIT

I tried solution of @pleft and it work. and I knew -  I use ajax for call method

```
function downloadResolution(resulutionId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/downloadResolution/' + resulutionId,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, str) {
            }
        });
    }
```

How realize this if I use ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `OutputStream` of your `HttpServletResponse` to write your archive bytes there.

e.g.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
response.getOutputStream().write(archive);
```

**EDIT**

Sample download

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadResolution/{resolutionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void downloadResolution(@PathVariable("resolutionId") Long resolutionId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String test = "new string test bytes";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.txt");
    response.getOutputStream().write(test.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: Not shows window for save file when I press "download" and downloadResolution method been executed

Comment: Are you sure your `resolutionArchive` is not null? Because in your code I see `if (resolutionArchive == null) return;` hence nothing will happen if your program returns. Can you debug it?

Comment: Yes I am sure. It is NOT NULL.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with a very trivial code for downloading as a text file a String. I have tested it and it works for me (spring-boot). If it doesnt work in your project then something other might be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried with another browser? IE, Firefox, Chrome? I tested my sample with all browsers and it works. Also did you check your logs for any exception?

Comment: ooo mayby I call method from ajax?

Comment: I dont think you can download a file via AJAX normally. You have to do some tricks, please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request BUT this is something completely different from your initial question.

Comment: I have a similar issue and i can download files on client side from spring controller. However, I also want to return a map (of records and other info) in the same api call.