# Open/Save dialog with ajax notification messages

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want Open/Save file dialog appears on page with notification about execution status.

**JSP**:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    function call() {
                      var msg = $('form').serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: 'compressor',
                          data: msg,
                          success: function(data) {
                            $('#results').html("Success");
                          },
                          error: function(xhr, str){
                             $('#results').html("Failed");
                          }
                        });
                    }
                </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Web compressor</h2>
    <form method="post" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
        <table>
           /*input*/
        </table>
    </form>
     Result: <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

**Servlet**:
On input servlet gets, source file path and creates temporary file. After that i use:

```
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="fileName");
```

And write file to OutputStream. But dialog pop-up doesn't appear, only "Success" message. Without ajax it works correctly. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download file using an ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request)

Comment: where is the code to invoke a dialog? and what is the dialog supposed to show?

Comment: <form method="post" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
It invokes ajax method after submiting form.