# Can not download files using Google Drive APIs V3

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download files using Google Drive APIs V3 with `alt=media` option. But I can't start download in a web browser.

My query is:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
```

Its response is something like:

[image: See the response of the query]

I've tried the third option which is `webContentLink` with this one I can start download directly in browsers but I couldn't download files larger than 25MB.

**So my question is :** how can I start the download in browsers via the Google APIs ?

Comment: its a file stream have you tried saving the response to a file locally?   I don't think you are going to be able to download a file larger then 25 mb in the browser.  https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Comment: I've tried using Blob, but there's a size limitation , for exemple, images larger than 10 MB can't be downloaded  using Blob and the browsers either crash or the downloaded element will be named at the download bar 'download Failed - Network error'. I am trying to figure out how I can download any file directly in the browser via the Google Drive API V3.

Comment: what are the response headers, i.e. is it setting content-type?  For me both content-type and content-disposition: attachment are set correctly.

If you are starting this via javascript, you may need to follow these instructions http://stackoverflow.com/a/20830337/1542667

Comment: There are 16 attributes is the response headers. The content-Type in my case is 'image/jpeg' and Content-Disposition is 'attachment'.

Answer (score 0):

To download anything from Google Drive API using REST or Web, you need to know the `webContentLink` of the file. `webContentLink` of the file is obtained by making a call to [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get).

The response is a link which downloads the file. However note that when you exceed the 25MB limit, Google might ask you about the 'scanning for virus' prompt. After that you'll be able to download the file directly.

Here's what my 30MB webContentLink looks like:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=ABCDEFGccNwI7MkxfZHB5NzRfSVU&export=download
```

After the "scan for virus prompt", I was able to download it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to know how did you manage the 'scan virus prompt' on your application?

Comment: when i opened the webContentLink on browser, i just clicked 'Yes'. After that it went on to download the file.