# Angular is blocking file download

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

When I initiate a `get` request in angular against a `webapi` controller that responds with a file wrapped in an `HttpResponseMessage` the browser doesn't recognize that it's a file download and the data is lost.

I checked in fiddler and I can see that the binary data is present in the response.

I'm initiating the get request with this:

```
      return $http.get(serviceURLRoot + 'api/myreport/' + dateParams.StartDate + '/' + dateParams.EndDate, { withCredentials: true }).success(function (data) {
      });
```

If I type the request directly into the address bar I get the file back just fine. Using `window.open` also works:

```
window.open(serviceURLRoot + 'api/rawdatareport/' + dateParams.StartDate + '/' + dateParams.EndDate);
```

Why doesn't `$http.get` work?

EDIT -----

Here's the HttpResponseMessage as built on the server:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pck.GetAsByteArray());
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
    FileName = "myReport.xlsx"
};

return result;
```

Comment: what are you doing with response? Ajax by itself won't iniitalize a file save dialog

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure if you mean on the server or the client. I've updated the question to show how the response is built on the server. On the client side it's just the `return $http.get` statement shown, there's nothing elided.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing an AJAX request with $http. The only way the browser is going to realize a file is coming is to have the browser go there. Realizing a file is coming, not HTML, it pops up the download. So you really have to change the location to that URL or open a new window in that URL.

Comment: there are ways to do downloads with ajax, answer is a bit inaccurate and incomplete

Comment: or `window.location`, yes. You can see related answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20830309/1658906 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4545311/1658906.

Comment: There is also a way using an iframe used by this library: http://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js