# Download link without redirection php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create button to download a file with an ajax call but the ajax call get the file content  on the response but doesn't create the download,(the download file is correct,the download is created if you type the url)

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="export-btn">
    <button class=" btn btn-success">Exportar</button>
</div>
```

the ajax call

```
$('#export-btn').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "download.php",
        method:'get'
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

and this is the download file,that works correct

```
<?php
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cataleg_peticions.csv"');

    $url = "cataleg_peticions.csv";
    readfile($url);
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20830337/6140684)

Comment: ajax is for downloading content. you cannot make a file download using ajax

Comment: And how I can doit?

Comment: just use anchor tag and add download.php file url in href. will not redirect to that page and direct download if u put header parameter as u mention.