# Download file returned from the onClick method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a function that makes an API call which returns a URL - how can I start a download with that link.

So I have the function:

```
function myF() {

  $.ajax{
     //Some GET cal

     return url
  }

}
```

And then a button:

`<button onclick="myF()">some</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try html5 `download` attribute, see example:

```
$.ajax({
    // config
}).then((res) => {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = 'your file name';
    a.href = res.data.url;
    a.click();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax{
//your request
success: function() {
        window.location = '<YOUR_URL>'; //url that you got from response
    }
}
```

This works if your response url is in the same origin.

You can find about more here : [download file using an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request)

Comment: Thanks - although I've read about using the html5 download tag - any other way/should I be using that?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple URL, I prefer to use an `<a>` element, and then give it a button appearance in CSS:

```
<a href="download-url" class="btn">Click here to Download</a>
```

And if it's a URL generated in JavaScript, you can add the url via DOM manipulation:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].href = "download-url";
```