# How To Download a pdf File with python to local machine

Tags: django, python-2.7, ftp

I have created the web application using Django 1.11 , I need to download files over the FTP or HTTP to my local system from application (Using Browser) using python.

HTML Code:

```
.....
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
<div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="download_payslip(10)">Download</button>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
.....
```

JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function download_payslip(emp_pay_id){
var dataString="&csrfmiddlewaretoken=" +$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
dataString+='&emp_pay_id='+emp_pay_id
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'/payslipgen/render_pdf/',
  data:dataString,
  success:function(data){
      Console.log(data)
  },
  error: function (err) {
    alert("Error");
  },
})
}
</script>
```

URL code:

```
url(r'^payslipgen/render_pdf/$', views.download_payslip, name='DownloadPaySlip')
```

Views:

```
def download_payslip(request):
    file_path = "/home/ubuntu/hrmngmt/hrmngmt/static/myfile.pdf"
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse

def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename='payslip.pdf'
            return response
    raise Http404
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is downloading in server where my python code is running, I need to download to my local system. I have already PDF file in server where my application is running , that pdf file should download to my local system using application (Application is created using Django 1.11)

Comment: storing file on server  may cause storage problem :(

Comment: I have edit my question, after response from sever , i can see the response data in console , but I don;t know how to convert to pdf, could you please help me

Comment: @Exprator , It's not working, in server I am getting response 'HTTP/1.1" 200' but , when it reach to javascript, in  ajax function any code need to add.

Comment: go through this link, you will understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request

Comment: @Exprator still not working , , any other way to do this using django application