# Downloading large CSV file - href unintentionally truncating results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I'm attempting to download a CSV file using the href method, however it appears data is truncated when setting it to a href tag. 
For IE I used msSaveBlob and that appears to be working correctly and all data is correctly downloaded.

```
            if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' }), filename);
            }
            //
            var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + data;
            var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
            //
            link.setAttribute("download", filename);
            link.innerHTML = "CSV Link - Placeholder";
            document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

            link.click();
```

These are relatively large files, 9k lines in excel (around 500kb).
Any ideas what I can do to stop this truncation? Should I use a different method? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using below answer:
[download file using an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request/42815974#42815974)

Essentially:

```
            var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
            if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
            else { // Others
                var a = document.createElement("a"),
                url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.body.removeChild(a);
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
                }, 0); 
            }
```