# Download XML after generated in Ajax Call

Tags: php, ajax, xml

I am trying to build a function that exports and XML as download. I use the `XMLWriter` function from PHP which works great. I actually get the result I want, only, it comes back in my AJAX response rather than it's opted as a download, which i told the script to do so.

My layout is as followed:

JS + AJAX

```
// ///////////////////////////// //
// START EXPORT                  //
// ///////////////////////////// //

function exports(vars){

    $.ajax({

        url: domain + "/core/ajax/export.php",

        type: "post",

        dataType: "text",

        data: vars,

        success: function(data){

            if(vars.form == 'export-records'){



            }

        },

        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage){

            console.log("Error: ", errorMessage);

        }

    });

}

$('#export-propperties').bind('submit',function(){

    event.preventDefault();

    var content = $('#export-propperties').serializeArray().reduce(function (newData, item) {

        if (item.name.substring(item.name.length - 2) === '[]') {

            var key = item.name.substring(0, item.name.length);

            if(typeof(newData[key]) === 'undefined') {

                newData[key] = [];

            }

            newData[key].push(item.value);

        } else {

            newData[item.name] = item.value;

        }

        return newData;

    }, {});

    exports(content);

});
```

So what happens here is i submit my form as a key value pair into my ajax function. Works fine. The php proces is as follows.

```
        // START THE XML HERE
        // AFTER THE DATA IS FETCHED WE WILL PARSE IT NORMALLY. WE ARE GOING TO USE THE RESULT LATER, FIRST WE CREATE THE INSTANCE OF THE FILE
        // TO DEFINE FIRST THE XML

        $writer = new XMLWriter();  

        $writer->openURI('php://output');  

        $writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');  

        $writer->setIndent(4);   


        // CREATE THE HEADING OF THE PRODUCTDATA

        $writer->startElement('ProductData');  

            $writer->writeAttribute('xmlns:xs', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');  

            $writer->writeAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.gs1.nl/productgegevens/insbou/004');  

            $writer->writeAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');  

            $writer->writeAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.gs1.nl/productgegevens/insbou/004 Productgegevens_insbou004.xsd');  

            // blablabla xml generation //

        $writer->endElement();  

        // END OF DOCUMENT

        $writer->endDocument();   

        $writer->flush();
```

The problem is that my response of the code is XML, rather than the wanted XML download (`$writer->openURI('php://output');`). I have a feeling I cant execute the download window within the AJAX call, or am I wrong here? How can I solve this?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request answer your problem.

Comment: @NigelRen no sorry, it doesnt work that way cause my data only get send once to my file. If it reopens because of it is successfully executed, i dont have my variables on which my export happens. The trick does work, but isnt the solution i can work with.

Comment: I removed for now the AJAX call out of it. Since i marked the target page as a download page in the header (which works) it sticks to the original page where my page is, so no harm done on this part. AJAX and downloads dont play nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.xml"');` in the top of your PHP code will work. I'm not sure, but give it a try.
Another solution is [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).
Sorry for my English.

Comment: removed the ajax call and added this to it, works good, thanks. I ll mark it as awnser, despite not being totally the right thing. A bit of googling helped me along that AJAX just doesnt play nice when it comes to downloading.