# How to return csv file from json data using Flask?

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, export-to-csv

I am trying to send to my flask app json data and having it return a CSV file. My ajax request is sending JSON data to the view via POST request and then the view is supposed to return back a csv file.  However, it fails to return the csv file in the browser as a download.  I'm not sure how to make it work or if its even possible. Thanks!

```
// AJAX - Send data over to python and return csv 
$("#export").click(
    function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/dbCSV",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            dataType:"json",
            data: JSON.stringify(datam)
        });
    
        event.preventDefault();
    }
);
```

```
@analyzers.route("/dbCSV", methods=["GET","POST"])
def dbCSV():
    if request.method=="POST":
        data = pd.DataFrame(request.get_json())
        resp = make_response(data.to_csv())
        resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
        resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
        return resp 
    return jsonify({"msg":"Could not generate CSV File"})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `send_file(...)` with a `BytesIO` (file stream) object:

```py
from io import BytesIO

from flask import send_file
...

response_stream = BytesIO(data.to_csv().encode())
return send_file(
    response_stream,
    mimetype="text/csv",
    attachment_filename="export.csv",
)
```

Keep in mind that you will not be able to open the download prompt when sending a POST request using AJAX. Instead, you will simply receive the file as an AJAX response. To solve this issue, you will have to take a look at this question:

[download file using an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request)

Maybe your code was already working and this was your problem – I can not tell from looking at it.

Comment: Of course this would have to be added to the function, otherwise the `return` statement would make no sense here ;)

Comment: I've tried this and its not letting me download the file still. I even added `window.location="/dbCSV";` to the success portion of the ajax call and its still not working.

Comment: Can you debug that you are actually sending the response (e.g. by adding some `print`'s along the function)? Also, try adding a GET endpoint that does not require any parameters and just returns the CSV of e.g. `pd.DataFrame(numpy.array([1, 2]))`, then you can test it using your browser by navigating to the corresponding URL.

Comment: I tried adding a bunch of print statements around the dataframe and the send_file piece and that part where the JSON data gets converted to a dataframe and then converted to a CSV file is working just fine. For whatever reason I still am not seeing the csv download. I also try using an `<a>` tag around the button IE `<button> <a href="/dbCSV"> Export </a></button>` which didnt work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out. Basically I can store the user input using the `session` object available from the `flask` library.  This allows different functions to access this rather then having to worry about creating global variables or passing them around via functions or objects.

**Note 1-** If the amount of user data that has to be saved is extensive then using `Redis` or some other type of in memory data storage would be a better choice in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Save the csv file in static path and then use the that static path csv URL to get csv file in download form from browser.