# Create Zip archive on the server and download it client-side

Tags: javascript

How do I transfer a zip archive generated on the server back to the client? I'm using AngularJS and SailsJS. Currently I set the HTML headers to match the content type, generate the archive using archiver and pipe the data into the res obejct before calling res.end().

The file-data is succesfully placed inside the XHR response, but the file is never downloaded on the clients side - unless I make an API call to zipFiles (see the code below).

How do I fix this?

```js
  zipFiles: async function (req, res) {
    var archiver = require('archiver');

    var year = req.allParams().year;
    var quarter = req.allParams().quarter;

    /*
     * FIXME: This is dangerous, the same code is present in api/controllers/sirka/SirkaShStatController.js
     * FIXME: A globally-available file should contain all relevant paths
     */

    var src_path = __some__path__

    var file_name = `download.zip`;

    // Set HTML headers to match the contents of the respone
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${file_name}`,
    });

    var archive = archiver('zip');

    archive.on('error', function(err) {
      throw err;
    });

    // Once the archive has been finished (by archive.finalize()) send the file
    archive.on('finish', function() {
      sails.log.info('Archive finished, sending...')
      res.end();
    });

    // Pipe the archive data into the respone object
    archive.pipe(res);

    // Append files found in src_path at the top level of the archive
    archive.directory(src_path, false);

    archive.finalize();
  }
```

Comment: _“but the file is never downloaded on the clients side”_ - of course it isn’t; with XHR/AJAX, you are making a _background_ request, so this is not _supposed_ to hassle the user with any download dialogs automatically from there. If you want to trigger a download dialog from this environment, you need to perform additional steps, see duplicate for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [download file using an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, the answer you linked did help me a bit, if you're interested in my final solution check out the accepted comment where I described my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and tinkering I've finally managed to solve the issue. I'll try to explain the different approaches that I took and their results.

**1st approach**
Generate the ZIP-file in-memory and transfer the binary data back to the user through the request.

This approach failed (see original question) since the call to zip the files was done through XHR/AJAX, even though it was possible to pipe the data into the response, it coulnd't be fetched on the client side.

**2nd approach**
Create the zip-file on the server, then represent the binary data as a Buffer. With this approach, I could simply return the buffer back to the caller by calling `res.ok(data)` once the zip-file was fully generated:

```js
var archiver = require('archiver');
var archive = archiver('zip');
var fs = require('fs');

var output = fs.createWriteStream(dst_path);

archive.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});

    // Once the archive has been finished (by archive.finalize()) send the file
archive.on('finish', function() {
   sails.log.info('Archive finished, sending...');
});

output.on('close', function () {
   var data = fs.readFileSync(dst_path);
   console.log(data);
   console.log(Buffer.byteLength(data));
   return res.ok(data);
})

// Pipe the archive data into the response object
archive.pipe(output);

// Append files found in src_path at the top level of the archive
archive.directory(src_path, false);

archive.finalize();
```

Then on the client-side I simply receive the data, convert it to `Uint8Array` and wrap it with another array. The wrapping is necessary since the data makes up one whole part of the Blob.

Then once the Blob is generated, I create an ObjectURL for it and attach the link to an invisible `a` element that is automatically clicked.

```js
var dataBuffer = res["data"];
var binaryData = new Uint8Array(dataBuffer);
var blobParts =  [binaryData];

var blob = new Blob(blobParts, {type: 'application/zip'});
var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = downloadUrl;
a.download = `Sygehusstatistik-${year}-K${quarter}.zip`;
a.click()
```

I've had issues with the generated zip-file getting placed into itself recursively, in order to avoid that ensure that `src_path != dst_path`

Comment: What a waste to buffer up the zip in browsers memory, if the file comes from the server use content-disposition header and *go* to the link from ether navigation, submit or hidden iframe. or `a[href=url][download=name]` there is no need to involve client side download functionality

Comment: To be fair this pattern of using navigation/download URL has a few downsides: url has to be kept short, so if you have a lot of config for a file export you need a non standard "body" in your GET requests ; the code feels clumsy if you want to trigger the download without navigation (adding a link in DOM and cliking it)...
But indeed it's better than a blob in browser RAM.