# Problem Returning file from ASP.NET Core MVC Controller- File is not downloaded

Tags: c#, download, asp.net-core-mvc, httpresponse

I'm trying to build a "download" button that starts a file download in the browser.

Here is my Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("AdminTools/{batchId}/DownloadAnswers")]
    public async Task<FileResult> DownloadAnswers(int batchId)
    {
        string fileName = "test.txt";
        byte[] filebytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");

        return File(filebytes, MimeHelper.GetMimeMapping(fileName), fileName);
    }
```

It is supposed to grab data from a database, and create a CSV file for delivery, but i've slimmed down the code.

In the view i have this button using knockout to data-bind click

```
 <button class="btn btn-light" data-bind="click: () => $parent.downloadAnswers(line.BatchId)"><i class="fad fa-file-download fa-fw"></i> Download </button>
```

and the code in my viewModel

```
 downloadAnswers(batchId: number) {
        Q($.ajax({

            url: `/Attestering/AdminTools/${batchId}/DownloadAnswers/`,
            type: 'GET'
        }));
    }
```

When I click the button I get this response:

```
Request headers:
GET /Attestering/AdminTools/91/DownloadAnswers/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: da-DK,da;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.QdXrCqqGsrk=CfDJ8KXm89uE_DNAripaOM8IAxzND7VK_PQPxpfmXtgTsKY1uN3acIgiucBdlkKaXs_eJvQu2Te066RjYnOlazo2P1oKclowja9hkxKhzrwIzq8GHhmsAhA_ZLQbMoFg59FeSEfExF04U6KJYk0W-Whhb1A
Host: localhost:7777
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://localhost:7777/attestering/admintools
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

And this Reponse header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 07 Mar 2023 13:34:44 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt; filename*=UTF-8''test.txt
```

And this Reponse

```
Hello World!
```

But I don't get the file download.

I've been searching and trying many different things. Mostly on the controller side.

Any hints ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [download file using an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller side is OK,if you could get the correct content-type with `MimeHelper.GetMimeMapping(fileName)`, you failed just because you tried with an ajax call,you would get the content of the file (for example as string) in resopnse of ajax call instead of the file

I tried with the two solutions,hopes could help:

```
<input type="button" onclick="downloadtxt()" value="DownloadTxt"/>

<input type="button" onclick="downloadcsv()" value="DownloadCSV"/>



<script>
    function downloadtxt(){
        window.open("/Home/DownloadTxt")        
    }

    function downloadcsv(){
       var eleForm = $("<form method='get'></form>");
       eleForm.attr("action","/Home/DownloadCsv");
       $(document.body).append(eleForm);
       eleForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<FileResult> DownloadTxT( )
        {
            string fileName = "test.txt";
            byte[] filebytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");

            return File(filebytes, "text/plain", fileName);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<FileResult> DownloadCSV()
        {
            string fileName = "test.csv";
            byte[] filebytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");

            return File(filebytes, "text/csv", fileName);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes. the problem was the AJAX call, we solved it by changing the html tag from <button> to <a>
<a class="btn btn-light" data-bind="attr: {href: '/Attestering/AdminTools/' + line.BatchId + '/DownloadAnswers' }"><i class="fad fa-file-download fa-fw"></i> Download </a>

Thanks.