# Return APK file from API REST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

Is it possible create an endpoint to return an `APK` file via `HTTP` request to the API?

Example:

`http://localhost:3333/v1/apk/latest`

In case of yes, is it the best way to do it?

Comment: looks good to me!

Comment: please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056246/node-js-serve-a-file-apk-in-particular-upon-successful-authentication-on-a-ge)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using express, best way to do it is using `res.download()` to force the browser to prompt the user for download.

Here's the doc, containing the download function args : https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html