# How to import JSON form server and download as Excel file in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, json, excel, angular

I currently have JSON/XML file in my server and I would like to know how to import the file/download to an excel sheet(xlsx) using Angular2 transcript. Additionally, it would be better if i can also export my excel sheet to the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2

Comment: Angular 2 is a framework for rendering a website, not transcoding files.

Comment: I followed the steps and ended with a corrupted/blank file, just like him. Is there an update on what i have to do?

Comment: @rinukkusu Angular is a development platform for building mobile and desktop web applications. Rendering is a small, limited, part of that.