# How to properly download excel file with Angular2

Tags: excel, angular, content-type, angular2-http

This is the code of my service which makes post request with response an xls file :

```js
exportInternalOrder(body) {
        let user_token: string = this.sessionService.getToken();
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('responseType', 'arraybuffer');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user_token);
        return this.http.post(this.config.exportInternalOrder, body,{
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => new Blob([res._body],{ type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }));
    }
```

Which is supposed to handle response of excel file.
This is the code invoking it:

```js
let objToSend = this.makeObjToSend(false);
this.reportingService.exportExcel(objToSend)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.exportData(data);
        },
        error => {
            this.errorFilterMsg.push({ severity: 'error', detail: 'Report exporting has failed!' });
        }
);
```

And this is the saving of the file (for some reason window.open does nothing):

```js
exportData(data){       
        let blob = data;
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = 'fileName.xls';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();        
    }
```

But the file still saves as corrupted one. While using postman and curl it comes ok. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you show us the `data` in `exportData(data)`. just want to check what's coming in `data`.

Comment: This is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771041/angular2-download-excel-file-from-web-api-file-is-corrupt/44680057#44680057

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 download excel file from Web API, file is corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771041/angular2-download-excel-file-from-web-api-file-is-corrupt)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`responseType` shouldn't be set in `headers`, it's part of `RequestOptionsArgs` object which is passed as second argument in `post` function and `RequestOptionsArgs` contains `headers`, `responseType` and others, you can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html). So, your code should look like this:

```js
import { ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

exportInternalOrder(body) {
    let user_token: string = this.sessionService.getToken();
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user_token);
    return this.http.post(this.config.exportInternalOrder, body,{
        headers: headers,
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
    }).map(res => new Blob([res._body],{ type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }));
}
```

Comment: MY Serbian neighbourhood friend!!! You just can not imagine how much you HELPED me with this post! Thanks thanks and again THANKS!

Comment: I am doing this: return this.http.post(endpoint, body, {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}).map(
  (res) => {
    return res.blob()
  }
); But I get this error: "Type ResponseContentType.Blob is not assignable to type json"... Any Idea ??

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this..it will be helpful for others who are looking for Angular 2 solution for file download functionality. Below piece of code works for me.

```
import { ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

exportInternalOrder(body) {
    let user_token: string = this.sessionService.getToken();
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user_token);
    return this.http.post(this.config.exportInternalOrder, body,{
        headers: headers,
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}).map(res => new Blob([res.blob()],{ type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }));
}
```