# Getting Syntax error in Response data in angular4 while trying to download an excel file

Tags: excel, angular, django-rest-framework, angular4-httpclient

I'd like to download an excel file by clicking a button in my angular Page.
When a user clicks the `button`, the click event triggers a service-method call:

```
downloadExcel(){
    this.componentService.getExel().subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("To Download:", data);      // this part is not executed, throwing Syntax Error* shown below
          //Here, function called to download excel-file with data
        }
   );
}
```

The Service:

```
getExel(){
    let url = 'http://url/endpoint/';
    return this.httpClient.get(url);
}
```

**Syntax Error:

> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at poisition 0 at
>   JSON.parse

In Django REST Framework Side:

```
class GetExcel(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
       with open('path/to/excel/file', 'rb') as tempfile:
           tempdata = tempfile()
           ResponseData = HttpResponse(tempdata, content_type='application/vnd...')
           ResponseData['Conetent-Disposition']="attachment; filename=%s" %Filename
       return ResponseData
```

So, I couldn't figure out where I made the mistake. And Please tell how to fix it.

Comment: use `map` operator  see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43278676/5695162)

Comment: I tried with this but it's not working, I worked on xhr as mentioned by @ForestG but I had to again write function to download it but later I used window.location.assign(URL) as it's a GET call and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

`...Unexpected token P in JSON at poisition 0 at JSON.parse`

So in the response object, where the HTTPClient api tries to parse the response from the `httpClient.get(url)` call, there is a JSON format error. The problem is in the `data` object, but it is caused by the HTTP response itself being malformatted.

Comment: Yes, that's right, Thanks for pointing out. Could you please suggest how to solve it?

Comment: in your browser's dev tool, what do you see on network tab when you click the event? Is it an XHR (XMLHTTPRequest) data? If yes, then it should be parsed by the browser to a JSON object. If not, than change this data so it won't contain any invalid characters. But, if it is _not_ an XHR data, but some datastream of an excel file, you should find a libary, which can handle it - and also, do not request it over http.  Google for solutions about that. (for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771041/angular2-download-excel-file-from-web-api-file-is-corrupt/44680057)

Comment: Yes, I found the data is of 'xhr'  type and followed the instruction (2nd way) in the link you provided. I was able to fetch the blob data but question rises again how to save/download the xlsx file. I found these service call is appropriate for POST call. I googled lil and found 
    `window.open(this.restUrl, "_blank");`  to use in click event function instead of a service get method.

Comment: Point to add:     `window.location.assign(URL)` This works better as it don't redirect to any other window/tab in broswer, just download the file.

Comment: @SamCodes Its really helpful. Worked for me too. I have tested the thing both in Win & Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look in this post: [how-to-properly-download-excel-file-with-angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276726/how-to-properly-download-excel-file-with-angular2). This is more or less similar to your requirement.

Comment: I tried with this but it's not working, I had to work on `xhr` as mentioned by @ForestG later I used window.location.assign(URL) as it's a GET call.

Comment: That's fine. I used that window.location.assign(URL). Its simple.