# How to download .xls file in angular 6 using file saver

Tags: javascript, angular6

I was trying to download .xls file from server but it's throwing error like in below:->

error is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
>   () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:31219:51) at
>   ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2761:31) at Object.onInvokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72221:33) at
>   ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2760:36) at
>   Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2528:47) at
>   ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2836:34) at invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3880:14) at
>   XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3906:17) text: "��ࡱ�;��   "

In my component, i implemented function which call service and i am using file saver to save a file, but its throwing error.

download.component.ts:->

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
     export_licence(){
        this.service.export_licence().subscribe((file: Blob) => {
          FileSaver.saveAs(file,'degreeCertificate.xls');
        }, (err) => {
          console.log("Download Error:", err);
        });
      }
```

download.service.ts :->

```
export_licence() {
  return this.http.post(this.export_licence_url,{responseType: "blob"});
}
```

I should be able to download .xls file from server, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [downloading xlsx file in angular 2 with blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996962/downloading-xlsx-file-in-angular-2-with-blob)

Answer (score 0):

Check the response Header set properly (For content type) and also ensure the file is not corrupted.

Seems Duplicate  [downloading xlsx file in angular 2 with blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996962/downloading-xlsx-file-in-angular-2-with-blob)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

download.component.ts:->

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
     export_licence(){
        this.service.export_licence().subscribe((file: Blob) => {
          FileSaver.saveAs(file,'degreeCertificate.xls');
        }, (err) => {
          console.log("Download Error:", err);
        });
      }
```

in service i added header properly.

download.service.ts:->

```
export_licence() {
  let headers = new Headers({ 
    'Content-Type':'application/json', 
    'Accept': 'application/.xls'
 });
 let options = { headers : headers };
  return this.http.post(this.export_licence_url,options,{responseType: "blob"});
}
```