# export html to xlsx using angular 7

Tags: javascript, excel, angular7, export-to-excel

I have tried to download my complex html table to excel using javascript code in angular 7.

```
<button (click)="export_xls('exportContent');" class="btn btn-success excelexport_btn float-right">Export TO Excel</button>

<div [innerHTML]="html_data" id="exportContent">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>

export_xls(element) {
  var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
  tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';

  tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';

  tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
  tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

  tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
  tab_text = tab_text + document.getElementById(element).innerHTML;
  tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

  var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';

  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
      if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
          var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
              type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
          });
          navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Test file.xls');
      }
  } else {
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.href = data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
        downloadLink.download = 'Test file.xls';
        downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

This exports my html perfectly in excel file But there is issue with format . downloading format in (.xls) because of that showing error like format extension doesn't match and file corrupted or safe issue? in order, to fix issue download format extension will be (.xlsx) and after somany search I found one solution to download in xlsx in table2export and many package with jquery but I couldn't found solution with angular 7 implementation. Can anyone suggest me solution for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996962/downloading-xlsx-file-in-angular-2-with-blob

Comment: But my input in html table and we have few packages with angular that is not working from complex tables like tr inside structured table

Comment: code what I have given is working perfectly to my scenario only thing I need download in xlsx instead of xls, because of xls its showing corrupted and misplaced extension alert