# How to download multiple files as zip from local folder in angular

Tags: angular

I have a requirement to develop download all types of files from a folder as zip in angular. I am new in angular.How to do it?

I don't know how to do this  can you please help?

Comment: where do the files exist? and what are you using as your backend ?

Comment: My files are in C:/Files. I am using asp.net core API as back end

Comment: you have to serve the files from your backend, have public/private endpoints in your backend so that they can be accessed from your UI. Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail as I am new to this area?

Comment: Angular is running on client side so it does not have the access to files which you want to serve, so for serving correct files you need to have backend server which can serve the files wherever they exists

Comment: As I need to serve the file . Will I do this from my asp.net core API. Then how can I access this folder in angular

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to:

1. build an endpoint in your backend that your Angular (client) can sent a get request.This is a bit out of scope for angular but you may find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984590/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-net)
2. use the [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) to download the files.
   This is usually done in a service;
   your component will call that service, the service will create a GET request via the HttpClientModule.
3. When you get the response back, you'll need to handle it differently than other json response. You can view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112470/download-zip-file-using-angular) as a reference. I'd recommend using the propr
   `responseType:'arraybuffer'`
   solution which is less "hacky" event though the blob one will work as well.