# Download to computer from URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a server for which I send a request (ID) in response from the server I get a json, inside json i have field ImagePath with url to image. How can I download this picture?

html

```
<button md-raised-button (click)="DownloadImage(application.ApplicationId)">Download Image</button>
```

Component

```
 DownloadImage(applicationId:number)
    {
        var ID=applicationId;
        this.httpService.downloadImage(ID).subscribe((response)=>{
            console.log(response);
        })


    }
```

Service

```
downloadImage(applicationId:number)
{
         return this.http.get('http://192.168.0.138/api/GetPhoto?applicationId='+applicationId,{headers:this.headers})
                         .map((res:Response)=> res.json() as DownloadImage
                        );

}
```

JSON

```
Object {ImagePath: "http://192.168.0.138:80/Content/photos/29ef5a62-8a84-41cf-92d7-7b76da20357b.jpg"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To chain requests, you can transform the `Observable` to a `Promise`, and then call `.then()` on it, which will get the mapped result of the previous call as a parameter. I'm not going to add the code for downloading a file in angular2 because it has been answered repeatedly in a dozen of posts.

Service

```
downloadImage(applicationId:number) {
    const _self = this;
    return this.http.get(`http://192.168.0.138/api/GetPhoto?applicationId=${applicationId}`, {headers:this.headers})
       .map((res:Response) => res.json() as DownloadImage)
       .toPromise()
       .then(function(dlImage: DownloadImage) {
          // Launch second call to dlImage.ImagePath
          const options = new RequestOptions({headers: myHeaderObj});
          return _self.http.get(dlImage.ImagePath, options);
        });
  }
```

Component

```
DownloadImage(applicationId:number) {
    this.httpService.downloadImage(applicationId).subscribe(resp => {
          // ... See numerous other SO topics for examples
    });
}
```

Just make sure the pictures are served from the same domain, otherwise you will run into CORS issues (but this also has been solved in a dozen of SO posts).

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use regular html anchor tag with download attribute :)

**Note**: Replace the "response.ImagePath" based on what you name the variable in the controller.

```
<a [href]="response.ImagePath" download="download.jpg"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But I need to make it so that the request is sent and downloaded file based on the link that comes from the server. Is it possible to do so at all?

Comment: You can either use the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2 by transforming the data to blob, however you will have to download the file not the URL.

Or use a little hack: 
1. Call using (click) as you're doing already.
2. Get the response
3. Trigger click event of hidden button of the href I posted in the first anwser.