# Angular 2 Service, How to download excel from Web API

Tags: angular

I have this API end-point
http://localhost:59253/api/reports?reporttype=evergreen.
If I copy this url in the browser it will correctly download the excel file (.xlsx). Now I am trying to call this end-point from my angular service. This is the code in my service.

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

getReport() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:59253/api/reports?reporttype=evergreen')
    .map(res => res.totalBytes);
}
```

And from my component i'm calling the service like this:

```
submit() {        
    this.reportService.getReport()
        .subscribe(
            () => {
               console.log("success");
        }, err => {
                console.log('error');
            });                                  
}
```

In the network tap of browser I can see that I'm hitting the correct Url, yet it doesn't seem to work. No error, It just simply does nothing. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: You don't have `subscribe` or anything. How do you detect that there's no error? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I am calling this service from my component. There I am subscribing.

Comment: Did you read the link above? Please, provide all relevant code and explain *How do you detect that there's no error?*. Otherwise the question cannot get a quality answer and is considered off-topic.

Comment: I added the calling function. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: The thing you're describing could be caused by CORS. It responds normally, yet causes an error. But I don't see anything wrong here. Since there's error callback, it should be called if there's an error, including CORS errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to change your service code as like follows,

```
getReport() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:59253/api/reports?reporttype=evergreen')
    .map(res => res._body);
}
```

And then use the following code in your component

```
    submit() {        
        this.reportService.getReport()
            .subscribe(data => this.downloadFile(data)),//console.log(data),
                             error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
                             () => console.log("success");;                       
    }


     downloadFile(data: Response){
      var contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
      var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
      var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url);
    }
```

Please check blob has been created properly or not based on your `content type` and then if URL doesn't open the new window please check that you have already imported `'rxjs/Rx'` or not ;

Also, you need to check your headers at the time of creating blob object.

For more help please check the same type of question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14083).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

While I gave a On Up for Santosh Shinde's answer here, you can also use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library if you want to use a standard solution. This is supported across multiple browsers and relieves you of