# NET Core 2 | Angular 2 | Downloading Files

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to download a file using `angular 2` and `net core 2` as the API.

When user clicks the download link, they should be able to save file in their local machine.

Every answer I've previously looked at varies a lot, and I can't seem to understand/ get them to work.

Anyway, this is what I've got the server, I return a file stream

```
  var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempFilename);
  var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  var fileName = "test.xlsx";

  return File(content, contentType, fileName);
```

The stream is returned fine. It is now my understanding I have to create a blob on the client? And then read and save the blob or something?

Currently, on my client all I have a get request returning an observable.

Here is my component call to my service:

```
    this.reportService.generateDispensations(this.config).subscribe(data => {

    });
```

I am not really sure what to modify in the actual http call, to turn it into a blob or something

Comment: Looking at your problem I think the solution posted [here (How do I download a file with Angular2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2) will help.

Answer (score 0):

for a quick fix, if your file does not require authentication, you can just do it this way

```
const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/location/to/download/from`
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

> suppose you have data file in some folder name like "image" folder
>   which is in wwwroot folder. suppose you have file name abc.jpg in
>   image folder. To get this file, write below code to your html
>   component.

```
<a href="https://localhost:8438/image/abc.jpg" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

> remove base url with your.

Or you can use below method in component.ts , fileNameUrl is the full url of image.

```
DownLoadFilesUrl(fileNameUrl: any) {
        debugger;
        var filename: string[] = fileNameUrl.split('\\');
        this.getBlobFile(fileNameUrl).subscribe((data: Blob) => {
            debugger;
            let item = filename[filename.length - 1];

            let checkFileType = item.split('.').pop();
            var fileType: any;
            if (checkFileType == "txt") {
                fileType = "text/plain";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "pdf") {
                fileType = "application/pdf";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "doc") {
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "docx") {
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "xls") {
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "xlsx") {
                fileType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "png") {
                fileType = "image/png";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "jpg") {
                fileType = "image/jpeg";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "jpeg") {
                fileType = "image/jpeg";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "gif") {
                fileType = "image/gif";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "csv") {
                fileType = "text/csv";
            }
            if (checkFileType == "amr") {
                fileType = "AMR-WB";
            }
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: fileType })
            const blob1: Blob = data;
            const fileName1: string = item;
            const objectUrl: string = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement('a') as HTMLAnchorElement;

            a.href = objectUrl;
            a.download = fileName1;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();

            document.body.removeChild(a);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);

        });
    }



   getBlobFile(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
        return this._http.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
    }
```