# Download file from http post request - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

**UPDATED with res.send(data) instead of res.json(data)**

Using Angular 6 and NodeJS I am doing a web application.
I am trying to download a file from a http post request.

I send a request to the server like this. From my component I call a function in a service. In the component, I susbscribe to have the answer of the server and when I have it I create a new Blob with the response and I Use FileSaver to download the pdf.

Now, when I received the answer from the server, the client sees it like an error whereas the status is 200. The error message is:
*"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/api/experiment/regression"*
See the screenshot below.

**Component.ts**

```
this.api.postML(this.regression).subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
      let pdf = new Blob(res.data, { type: "application/pdf" });
      let filename = "test.pdf";
      FileSaver.saveAs(pdf, filename);
    },
    err => {
      alert("Error to perform the regression");
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

**API.Service.ts**

```
  public postML(data): Observable<any> {
    // Create url
    let url = `${baseUrl}${"experiment/regression"}`;

    let options = {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", Accept: "application/pdf" }
    };
    // Call the http POST
    return this.http
      .post(url, data, options)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Then from the server, it executes some code with the data sent and generates a PDF file.
Then, I would like to send the pdf as a response to the client.
I tried like this:

```
fs.readFile("/home/user/test.pdf", function(err, data) {
  let pdfName = "Report.pdf";
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.set("Content-Disposition", pdfName);
  res.set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
  console.log(data);
  console.log("Send data");
  res.status(200);
  res.send(data);
});
```

In the client, I have the answer. The console log is:
[image: console log]

Comment: This line doesn't look good `res.json(data);` Why JSON? it should be a byte stream, right?

Comment: You would be correct @rodrigoap. A json will download the object in a json format, not a PDF.

Comment: try `res.send(data)`

Comment: Take a look at https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback

Comment: I tried res.send(data) and I have an error even if the status is 200.
The message error is: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/api/experiment/regression"

Comment: @PierBJX, update the question with the new error, add the stacktrace and all the info you have.

Comment: @rodrigoap, I updated it

Comment: Now the issue is specific to Angular (I know nothing about Angular) and how you handle the response. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2

Comment: Don’t you think it’s because of the headers ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177825/discussion-between-rodrigoap-and-pierbjx).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Finally, I found a video tutorial and it was very basic.

**Node.js Server:**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/experiment/resultML/downloadReport",downloadReport);

const downloadReport = function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(req.body.filename);
};
```

**Angular Component:**

```
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
...

download() {
  let filename = "/Path/to/your/report.pdf";
  this.api.downloadReport(filename).subscribe(
    data => {
      saveAs(data, filename);
    },
    err => {
      alert("Problem while downloading the file.");
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
}
```

**Angular Service:**

```
public downloadReport(file): Observable<any> {
  // Create url
  let url = `${baseUrl}${"/experiment/resultML/downloadReport"}`;
  var body = { filename: file };

  return this.http.post(url, body, {
    responseType: "blob",
    headers: new HttpHeaders().append("Content-Type", "application/json")
  });
}
```

Comment: hello @PierBJX could you pls share github repo. am trying to download pdf file from my local folder. how to achieve this in angular 2+ ,nodeJS Expressjs

Comment: The code above explains how to do it. What else do you need ? Which points are you missing ?

Comment: This is what my issues..  Pls check my below post
https://stackoverflow.com/q/52968015/9552112

Comment: Alright, in my example it's post request and not a get request like you are doing

Comment: where does that `saveAs` function come from?

Comment: @FabioG It comes from file-saver npm: import { saveAs } from "file-saver";