# Angular and Nodejs basic file download

Tags: node.js, angular

Could someone show me an example of a user basic file download using Node and Angular please. I understand it like this, but this is not working:

Nodejs:

```
// Does it matter that it is a post and not a get?
app.post('/some-api', someData, (request, response) => {
    response.download('file/path/mytext.txt');
});
```

Angular 2+:

```
this.httpclient.post<any>('.../some-api', {...data...}).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
  // This throws an error, but even if it doesn't,
  // how do I download the Nodejs `response.download(...) ?`
});
```

Here are possible answers, but they are so complex, could someone just give me a super basic example (basically what I have here, but a working version). The easiest solution please.

[How do I download a file with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2)

[Angular download node.js response.sendFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231765/angular-download-node-js-response-sendfile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go..

**Node.js Server:**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/experiment/resultML/downloadReport",downloadReport);

const downloadReport = function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(req.body.filename);
};
```

**Component Angular:**

```
  import { saveAs } from "file-saver"
  download() {
    let filename = "/Path/to/your/report.pdf";
    this.api.downloadReport(filename).subscribe(
      data => {
        saveAs(data, filename);
      },
      err => {
        alert("Problem while downloading the file.");
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

**Service Angular:**

```
  public downloadReport(file): Observable<any> {
    // Create url
    let url = `${baseUrl}${"/experiment/resultML/downloadReport"}`;
    var body = { filename: file };

    return this.http.post(url, body, {
      responseType: "blob",
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append("Content-Type", "application/json")
    });
  }
```

Comment: Where does `saveAs()` come from?

Comment: its npm module file-saver npm: import { saveAs } from "file-saver"

Comment: Ok thank you. I think you can remove the `headers: new HttpHeaders().append("Content-Type", "application/json"` in `Service Angular`. It seems to work without it.