# How to download pdf file on button click in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to download the .pdf file on button click I am using the below code

```
downloadMyFile() {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        link.setAttribute('href', 'http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/books/pdf/aqua_imagica_visit_learnings.pdf');
        link.setAttribute('download', 'aqua_imagica_visit_learnings.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        link.remove();
      }

<button (click)="downloadMyFile()">download File</button>
```

But when I click button it is redirected on a new page but I want to download 'aqua_imagica_visit_learnings.pdf' file on download.
Kindly help me .
here is my  link [http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hjad7]

Comment: `<a [href]="VariableWithfileUrl" target="_blank" > download</a>` or just use regular link without any binding `<a href="http://parallax.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/books/pdf/aqua_imagica_visit_learnings.pdf" target="_blank" > download</a>`

Comment: just create a normal link like above , it will work

Comment: @joel  when I am using these code <a href="http://parallax.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/books/pdf/aqua_imagica_visit_learnings.pdf" target="_BLANK" > download</a>  it is working but it is redirected on a new page but i want download the pdf file i don't want to redirect

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download with ts:

```
 async download(id: number) {
        try {
            const res = await this.service.getDocument(id);
            this.downloadFile(res);
        } catch (e) {
            this.session.addSingleMessage(e.body.message);
        }
    }

    downloadFile(data) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        window.open(url);
    }
```

template:

```
<button click="download(1)>Download</button>
```

service:

```
 async getDocument(id: number): Promise<any> {
        this.session.setLoading();
        const resp = await this.httpClient.get(`/api/document/${id}/download`, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();
        this.session.resetLoading();
        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: thank you to reply, But i am not using api i want to download pdf file from URL.

Comment: then you can replace `/api/document/${id}/download` to your url

Comment: no i want to download from this URL "http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/books/pdf/aqua_imagica_visit_learnings.pdf"

Comment: change the href target from _blank to _self

Comment: when i am using _self so it overrides the my website page and directly pdf file is open.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-using-the-html5-download-attribute--cms-23880) .pdf file won't be downloaded if you use download attribute on anchor:

> Some file types, however, (such as images, .pdf, .txt, and .doc for example) won’t be downloaded. They, instead, will be opened in the browser.

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: @orlyohreally thank you to reply pls if you know the solution let me know.

Comment: @orlyohreally okay

Comment: @ArjunWalmiki try something of these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2

Answer (score 1):

Use inspect element and make sure your link looks something like this.
Instead of

```
link.setAttribute('download', 'aqua_imagica_visit_learnings.pdf');
```

try doing it this way.

```
link.download = "aqua_imagica_visit_learnings.pdf";
```

Comment: yes i try your solution but still, it is redirected on a new page.

Comment: can you try using any .img file to make sure that only some files like .PDFs have restriction in downloading?

Comment: yes i also try with .img downloadMyFile() {

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'http://designs.mydeievents.com/jq-3d-flip-book/books/image/2019-2020/Newlands_Year_Book/1.jpg');
    link.download = '1.jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  } but it is redirect on another page.

Comment: Please create a stackblitz for this so we can figure out the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line on your html code,it works for me:

```
<a href="download/acme.pdf" download="Acme.pdf">Download pdf file</a>
```