# Angular azure deployment: How to download .pbit (or any new file format) from angular app

Tags: angular, azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We have an angular app where I have added the .pbit (powerbi template) file in the local assets folder. The logic is upon clicking the menu it should download the .pbit file in downloads folder and allow the users to open the .pbit file and work on powerbi desktop **( Using Dynamic parameters to retrieve and build dashboard via web API)**

The above method is working fine if I serve from my local machine. Upon building the Angular production build along with the web.config file. When I host it in to `Azure App service`  and trying to execute the menu click I was initially ended up with the following error

> 'The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.'

Later in the web.config: I have added the following MIME type

```
 <mimeMap fileExtension=".pbit" mimeType="text/plain" />
```

But this is not downloading the file instead opening  weird ASCII Characters in browser like below.

[image]

Any experts can please advise what is the right MIME Type to include or any alternative solution to achieve this.

Comment: you should use blob storage

Comment: look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2