# Receive a photo file and save it in an array by Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the address of a photo and I want to put the file of that photo in the array but I have a problem
How to do it?

I did the following:

AppComponent.ts:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
  files:any[]=[];
  url:string="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Delete_key1.jpg"
  getImage(){
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.files.push(res);
        console.log(this.files)
      },
      err=>{
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

AppComponent.html:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="getImage()">Click Me</button>
```

console:

```
    Error
    error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "����JFIF,,���Photoshop 3.08BIM�…��-�� ���O�0��@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@��"}
    headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
    message: "Http failure during parsing for https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Delete_key1.jpg"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Delete_key1.jpg"
```

**I want to send the photos to the server after receiving them and I need to send the photo file, how do I put the photos in the file presentation?**

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want to download photos from a server and then send to them to another server as files. if yes, then you should download them as blob, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210392/755253), then save the blobs in to your array and do what you want.

Your code is trying to reading response as **json** which is standard in **http** call, that is what the error tried to say.

Comment: How can I fix my problem? Can you give me an example of code?