# How can I download an excel file in angular 6

Tags: c#, angular, excel, webapi

How do I download excel file at an angular 6

The file sent to my angular from C# as an array of bytes by webApi

The required format is **.xlsx**

```
 downloadFile(result, fileName) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(result).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
    var blb = new Blob([byteArray], { type: EXCEL_TYPE });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blb, fileName);
  }
```

(resulat = c# byte array)

Answer (score 3):

Try File Saver. That's what I use.

```
npm install file-saver --save
npm install @types/file-saver --save
```

This post may help you:

[How do I download a file with Angular2 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2-or-greater)

Cheers.