# Angular download file corrupted

Tags: angular

I want to create a service to download files from web API but files was corrupted when open but work fine when using postman.

Here is my code,

```
public downloadDocument(reqModel: any): void {
    this.documentService.download(reqModel).subscribe((response: any) => {
        const downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(response);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadURL;
        link.download = "test.jpg";
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
    }
}
```

```
public download(reqModel: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`www.test.com/download`, reqModel, { responseType: "blob" });
}
```

Result when open downloaded file.

[image]

When request with Postman the web API response an image as expected.

[image]

[image]

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35138424/7343259) should help you to resolve your issue