# Subscribe didn't receive a response to download the file

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, httpresponse

In my project, I'm using angular6 with Springboot backend. So what I'm trying to do is popup the save dialog using this controller java class,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getGeneratedLetter/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void genarateLetter(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println(userId);
        letterTypeService.genarateLetter(userId);
        try {
            // get Letter.docx from file path
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("Letter.docx");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = Letter.docx");
            IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IOError in " + ex);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** in my `letterTypeService` java class the letter will be generated correctly.

And finally, I'm catching the response in my angular front-end in my component,

```
getGenaratedLetterTemplate(letter) {
  this.data.getGenaratedLetterTemplate(letter.letterId).subscribe(response => {
    this.getBasicDataFromBackend();
    saveAs(response,  letter.fullName + '_' + letter.letterTypeName + '.docx');
    console.log(response);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

In above function responce will not catch since the result is

> error massage: "OK"

It's confusing because it displayed just "OK" there are not any specific error details. Additionally in my service in frontend successfully send get request and in-network tab in chrome dev tools displays "status code:200"
[image]

**Further investigation** When I copy and paste my get request URL in new browser window the letter download popup will be displayed successfully and when I click the save button the letter will download successfully.

So what could be the issue here?

Comment: You need the request options to pass the username/password as a header. It isn't received in your controller. The popup doesn't occur because you are doing an Ajax request, which is handled in the background of the browser.

Comment: @M.Deinum Updated my question, do you have any idea?

Comment: You are using AJAX to download the file, hence there will be no popup as the request/response is handled transparantly.

Comment: @M.Deinum So what should I do for fix this. Please can you elaborate?

Comment: Don't use AJAX if you want a popup but a regular link. You are doing a request in the background and hence everything is handled in the background. You need to do extra work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: is there an error in javascript console? I think there could be a cors related error messages

Comment: Shouldn't you return the response to be sent back?

Comment: @Andrei no there aren't errors in console

Comment: @thomi it should catch response correctly because when I'm pasting the requested url in new tab everything works fine

Comment: I am not quite sure. I think `void` controller methods return 200 OK implicitly if they don't fail. If you want to send something to your client, you need to return something. In your case it would be `return response`.

Comment: @thomi please can you elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As M. Deinum indicated. AJAX does the `GET` request transparently, so there will be no popup. You could build a link in your client, which you can click (same as if you copied the link into a new browser). E.g. I did something similar for an app of mine, where I have the following in my template:

```
 <a [href]="yourUrl" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
     <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <!-- or whatever you want to display -->
 </a>
```

And the `yourUrl` then would be the url to your backend. It should popup a download dialogue (I did not test it for files coming from the backend, but I think this should work).

**Edit**: 
[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771342/file-download-script-doesnt-work-when-called-from-ajax) suggests that you cannot download files directly with AJAX, primarily for security reasons. [This codepen](https://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/RKxJNo) shows how to do it with Javascript, but it basically does the same thing: It creates an anchor tag, puts the data into an [`objectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), adds it to the DOM, clicks it and removes itself again, so in the end you see a popup. The download attribute in the pen only works for same-origin requests, but since you set a `Content-Disposition` header, you could also leave it out ([here is some more information about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)). For this to work with Angular, you could basically take the code in the `success:` clause and copy it to your http call (I'd suggest replacing the `var`s with `const`s). It's not clean Angular however, because you directly interact with the DOM and if you use server-side rendering, you'd have to check for this. And it can cause memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try with this and please can you tell me what would be the reason for get AJAX request transparently

Comment: You are a life savior. this should earn more upvotes @thomi

Comment: NP, happy I could help.